# Palais–Smale compactness condition

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, compactness, calculus-of-variations

Can someone explain the essence of Palais–Smale compactness condition used in the Mountain Pass Theorem, in particular its weak formulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather natural: you are looking for a critical point of a functional $I \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a Banach space (in the most used form). Assume that you can, for some reason, construct a sequence $\{u_n\}_n$ of points in $X$ such that $DI(u_n)$ tends to zero and $I(u_n)$ cannot move off to infinity.
The Palais-Smale condition tells you that you can always extract a subsequence $u_{n_j}$ converging to an element $u \in X$.

This is very useful, since a mere continuity assumption like $I \in C^1(X)$ will tell you that $DI(u)=0$, i.e. $u$ is a critical point of $I$. Now your task is to construct such a sequence $\{u_n\}_n$. This can be done in at last two ways: the first is a corollary of the Ekeland variational principle. The second is an argument based on some deformation lemma, like in Morse theory. Actually most minimax theorems provide you with a Palais-Smale sequence, and the existence of a critical point comes from a compactness condition. A useful variant of the (PS) condition was introduced by Giovanna Cerami, and it is called Cerami condition. You can find many details in standard books: Willem, Struwe, and so on.

Comment: Indeed, the deformation lemma and, consequently, mountain pass theorem(s) make a good use of this condition. 
However, one thing that is still unclear for me is the presence of the word *compactness* in the title.
 
I can see that an unbounded functional will never satisfy this condition because of the "no infinity" constrain in definition. But why do they need to put so much stress on the compactness, why people don't just call it "Palais-Smale Condition"? Is there something else going on here with compactness I don't quite get, or is this name just a result of historical coincidence?

Comment: Many people call it "(PS) condition" actually. The point is that compactness is probably the most important ingredient in calculus of variations, and this condition is weaker than the compactness of the space/manifold as in baby Morse theory one assumes.